# Sveltekit & {#await}

Tags: javascript, async-await, svelte, pocketbase

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a file called *activitylog.js* and inside it is this

```
export async function getActivityLogList() {
    const resultList = await pb.collection('activitylog').getList(1, 50, {
      filter: `user.id="${pb.authStore.model?.id}"`
    });
  return resultList.items;
}
```

and inside my *+page.svelte* I call it using

```
{#await getActivityLogList()}
    <p>Loading...</p>
{:then log}
    <p>LOG: {log.length}</p>
    {#each log as logs}
        <p>{logs.name}</p>
    {/each}
{:catch error}
    <p>Error: {error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

But it always shows "Loading..."? The function `getActivityLogList()` definitely returns an array of items from pocketbase? so why isn't the `:then` being triggered once the promise is fulfilled

Comment: Do you get anything in the console?

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Not a single error in the console.. thinking this is a bug or my svelte isn’t setup correctly maybe, might just do a clean install of svelte and see

Comment: Is it possible to provide the code base? First, if you are using sveltekit why is the method in activityLog.js and not in +page.server.js?